# In bash got unwanted newlines after sed and cat >>

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting, hosts

I'm trying to substitute some lines in /etc/hosts file with my script here:

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts_file_path="/etc/hosts"

nas_servers=( 'mynas01' 'mynas02' )

strange_string="<00>"

for nas_name in ${nas_servers[@]}; do
    printf '%ls\n' "$nas_name"
    r="$(nmblookup "$nas_name")"
    if [[ ! -z "$r" ]] && [[ "$r" != "name_query" ]]; then
        l=${#r}
        ls=${#strange_string}
        cl=$(($l-$ls))
        echo "$cl"
        s="${r:0:cl}"
        printf '"%ls"\n' "$s"
        res="$(grep -i "$nas_name" "$hosts_file_path")"
        echo "$res"
        if [ ! -z "$res" ]; then
            sr="s/.*${nas_name}.*//g"
            echo "$sr"
            sed -i "$sr" "$hosts_file_path"
        fi
        printf '%ls\n' "$s" >> "$hosts_file_path"
    fi
done
```

It searches e.g. for lines like

```
192.168.1xx.xxx mynas01
```

and replaces the line (if it's found) with a sed command to nothing, but adds afterwards e.g. to

```
192.169.1xx.xxx mynas01
```

I'm having to do (?) this because my LAN network addresses are changing very often (exactly: at each working day, but not always in a working session), so editing everytime the /etc/hosts file is not very useful, even to setup stuff like SNMP is (for two servers) a little too much overhead for me - I just want o put this script in a cron job or in rc.local and to avoid smblookups.

Now my question(s): If I making it in this way, there will be more empty newlines after the end of file and/bewtween the added text, How can I avoid this and is there a shorter way for that?

Till now I got as result (/etc/hosts):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       hostname.fqdn.example.com    hostnam

(^ the space here got more and more by each call of my script, more newlines and more newlines) 


192.168.1xx.101 mynas01
192.168.1xx.102 mynas02
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `sed` command, instead of *deleting* the line of interest, turns it into an *empty* line, so in effect you *blank out* an old NAS entry while adding a new line for it, which keeps adding lines.

Use the following `sed` command instead, which *deletes* the matching line:

```
sr="/${nas_name}/ d"
```

or, more robustly, to rule out false positives:

```
sr="/[[:blank:]]${nas_name}[[:blank:]]*$/ d"
```

<sup>Since a *double-quoted* string is used, you generally have to use `\$` for `$` chars. that the shell should *not* expand.

However, the shell leaves something that is not a syntactically valid variable reference alone, so `$/` is passed through to `sed` as-is.

For stricter separation of the shell expanded part (double-quoted) and the Sed script (single-quoted), you can use the following, which, however, is harder to read: `sr='/[[:blank:]]'"${nas_name}"'[[:blank:]]*$/ d'`. Generally, though, it's a worthwhile approach.</sup>

Note that your script could be simplified in many ways, including using a single `sed` command to update the existing entry directly instead of deleting the old entry with `sed` first and then appending a new one with `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `grep -v` to remove the lines you don't like from the file.  It's much easier than `sed` after `grep` like you have now, and it won't leave you with blank lines.

Comment: But grep -v returns the invert search for ONE grep match. How can I do it for two or more strings (mynas01, mynas02,mynas03...)?

Comment: `grep -v` is perhaps slightly easier, but if you also want in-place updating of the input file (as is the case here), `sed -i` is handy, and the OP's only problem was using the `s` function to replace a matching line with an _empty_ string instead of using the `d` function to _delete_ it.

Comment: @aprogrammer: `egrep -v 'mynas[0-9]+'` is one way.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a /etc/hosts file that looks like this

```
192.168.111.000 mynas01
192.168.222.000 mynas01
192.168.333.000 mynas01
000.192.168.000 mynas01
```

you just need to do:

```
cat /etc/hosts | sed 's/^192\.168\./192\.169\./'
```

and you get

```
192.169.111.000 mynas01
192.169.222.000 mynas01
192.169.333.000 mynas01
000.192.168.000 mynas01
```

Comment: As you see there is a string list (or better: a name list of my nas, which I want to change: mynas01, ...)

Comment: How does the original /etc/hosts file look like?

Comment: It is unclear how your answer relates to the question.

Comment: The question is about _why new empty lines show up in the file_ after every run, and how to avoid them. The part of (effectively) _updating_ the entries works fine already - even though it is more cumbersome than it needs to be (delete old entry first, then append updated version). While using a direct substitution as you suggest is preferable, you're missing the point of the question.